Is there any real connection between homology and the sewing lemma/boundary operator in rough paths theory?
This question is concerned with the sewing lemma and "boundary operator" arising in rough paths theory. I give some background here.
Let $\Delta_1^T, \Delta_2^T,\Delta_3^T$ denote the $1,2,3$ simplices of $[0,T]$. Denote by $C_i$ the space of continuous functions $C_i:=C(\Delta_i^T,V)$ for real vector space $V$. Define the boundary operator $\partial:C_i\to C_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2$ by $(\partial f)_{s,t}=f(t)-f(s)$ and $(\partial g)_{s,u,t}=g_{s,t}-g_{s,u}-g_{u,t}$ for $f\in C_1$ and $g\in C_2$. It is easy to check the following proposition.

(Proposition) For $g\in C_2$ we have $\partial g=0$ iff there is some $f\in C_1$ with $g=\partial f$.

On the level of boundary operators, this is saying that $g$ is closed iff $g$ is exact.
The sewing lemma is an approximate version of this that is at the heart of rough paths theory (and generalizations such as the reconstruction theorem from regularity structures).

(Sewing Lemma) Let $g\in C_2$. Suppose that $(\partial g)_{s,u,t}=o(|t-s|).$ Then there is a (unique) $f\in C_1$ so that $g_{s,t}=(\partial f)_{s,t}+R_{s,t}$ with $R_{s,t}=o(|t-s|)$.

You can also check that the converse holds pretty easily. So in addition to $g$ closed iff $g$ is exact, we have that $g$ is approximately closed iff $g$ is approximately exact.
Both of these results look very suspiciously like homology. Is this just a coincidence or is there a real connection?

This is more a long comment. There is an obvious way to realize it as a relative cohomology, namely, it is the vanishing of the first cohomology modulo $o(\lvert t-s\rvert)$ (which forms a sub-complex), but I am not sure whether this one is the "correct" one to consider in your context. Let me spell out some details for non-experts.
I would shift the indices by 1 to make it a cosimplicial object. More precisely, as for you, we fix a non-negative real number $T$. We will denote by $E_n$ the collection of non-decreasing maps $\{0,\dots,n\}\to[0,T]$ endowed with the subspace topology of $[0,T]^{n+1}$, and by construction, we get a simplicial topological space $\newcommand\op{\mathrm{op}}\newcommand\Top{\mathbf{Top}}E_\bullet\colon\mathbf\Delta^{\op}\to\Top,[n]\mapsto E_n$.
Let $(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$ be a real normed vector space, and let $K^n$ denote the vector space of continuous maps $E_n\to V$ (which is $C_{n+1}$ in your notation). This gives rise to a cosimplicial vector space $K^\bullet\colon\newcommand\Vect{\mathbf{Vect}}\mathbf\Delta\to\Vect,[n]\mapsto K^n$, and your quoted proposition is saying that $H^1(K^\bullet)=0$.
Now we consider the cosimplicial subspace $L^\bullet\subseteq K^\bullet$ where $L^n\subseteq K^n$ is the subspace of continuous maps $f\colon E_n\to V$ such that

for every constant map $c\in E_n$, we have $f(c)=0$;
the following limit is zero: $$\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\sup_{\varphi\in E_n,0<\varphi(n)-\varphi(0)\le\delta}\frac{\lVert f(\varphi)\rVert}{\varphi(n)-\varphi(0)}=0.$$

This amounts to your $o(\lvert t-s\rvert)$. Then the sewing lemma is saying that $H^1(K^\bullet/L^\bullet)=0$.

This is interesting. Relative homology helps.

@user479223 I guess that all higher cohomology groups vanish (not just the first), and there might be more conceptual way to think about this cohomology, but I do not have time thinking further.

The similarity between the condition of the sewing lemma, $(\partial^2 g)_{s,u,t} = 0$, and the property of a boundary operator in a chain complex can be formalized as follows. Consider a sequence of spaces:

$C_0$, the space of functions of time;
$C_1$, the space of increments $g_{s,t}=g(t)-g(s)$;
$C_2$, the space of 2-increments $(\partial g)_{s,u,t}=g_{s,t}-g_{s,u}-g_{u,t}$;
and so on for higher-order increments.

Define the boundary operator $\partial : C_n \to C_{n-1}$ as follows. This constructs a chain complex: $$ \cdots \xrightarrow{\partial} C_2 \xrightarrow{\partial} C_1 \xrightarrow{\partial} C_0 \xrightarrow{\partial} 0. $$
The sewing lemma can thus be interpreted as a condition for an approximate chain map. If $(\partial g)_{s,u,t} = o(|t-s|),$ then the image of $\partial$ in $C_1$ is "almost" in the kernel of $\partial : C_1 \to C_0$.
Furthermore, consider the dual spaces $C_0^*$, $C_1^*$, etc., consisting of linear functionals on $C_n$. The boundary operator $\partial$ induces a dual operator $\partial^*$, resulting in the cochain complex:
$$
0 \to C_0^* \xrightarrow{\partial^*} C_1^* \xrightarrow{\partial^*} C_2^* \xrightarrow{\partial^*} \cdots.
$$
